# Order BY Most Liked And Published Between Previous Week Monday And Next Week Monday

Tags: php, wp-query, order, sort

I have a code which sorts the content by most liked, but I would like it to show the most liked in between previous week monday and next week monday. And the posts must be published in that time frame. Tho I have no idea how to sort by published date and most liked in that time frame. Grateful for help if anyone can. Using Ulike plugin to pull likes.

```
$loop = new WP_Query(
    array(
        'posts_per_page' => 6,
        'post_status' => 'publish',
        'post_type' => 'post',
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num',
        'meta_key' => '_liked',
            'date_query' => array(
            array(
                'after' => strtotime( 'monday previous week' ),
                'before' => strtotime( 'monday next week' )
            ),
        ),
        'paged' => (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1
    )
);
while ($loop -> have_posts()) : $loop -> the_post();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WordPress allows multiple orders with the orderby parameter. https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters

```
'meta_key' => '_liked', // You do it well
'orderby'  => array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC'),
```

Here you tell WordPress to sort by "bigger" likes and last publish date.

Comment: Semi-works, now it's still showing the posts before previous week monday unfortunately. I think my date query is wrong somehow?

Comment: Thanks I just finished it. My date query was wrong.

                                     'orderby'  => array('meta_value_num' => 'DESC', 'date' => 'DESC'),
                                        'date_query' => array(
                                         array(
                                        'after' => 'monday previous week',
          'before' => 'monday next week'
                                           ),
                                         ),